# Multiple transitions in react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

How can I change transitions with react-transition-group (2.4.0, if it matters)?

I currently have the following structure (with react-router)

```
<CSSTransition key={x} timeout={100} classNames={transition}>
    <Switch>
        <Route render={() => <span>foo</span>}/>
        <Route render={() => <span>bar</span>}/>
    </Switch>
</CSSTransition>
```

It works fine with a fixed `classNames`, except I would like some pages to have a different transition.

If I just change the `classNames` of the `CSSTransition`, it seems like it corrupts the state, it ends up putting the `-enter-done` class of the new animation, but the `-enter` class of the old one still remains.

Comment: I would like to help you.  Can you post more of the code?  Seems like you can/should be using `TransitionGroup` the way you have the props setup.  Also would be good to see how `x` and `transition` are set.

Comment: Hi @PsiKai, unfortunately this was a work project and I'm no longer at that company, so I'm afraid I don't have any more code. Thanks for the intention though!

Comment: Totally understandable.  I figured it was a long shot with such an old post, but I just wanted to help future generations if possible.